# is AT&T network possible on the Droid a855?

Tags: motorola-droid, verizon, mobile-network, att

Is it possible to use AT&Ts network on the Droid a855? At all possible? Tough to find a direct answer on the web for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Get your hands on a Motorola Milestone (the European versions of the Droid line). Those are all GSM phones. They are also all sold (at least internationally) unlocked, so you could take one to any US GSM carrier and use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Droid is a CDMA phone.  In general you can assume that phones on Verizon and Sprint won't work on AT&T or T-Mobile, and vice-versa.